# Checkout broken after update to Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: checkout, magento-1.9

Just upgraded to 1.9.0.1 and now "shipping methods" screen will not CONTINUE when CONTINUE button pushed during ordering - site is broken and no orders coming in - YIKES. Error messages coming into admin say:

Payment transaction failed.

Reason
Please specify a shipping method.

Checkout Type
onepage

THANKS MAgento Angels!

Comment: I see you are new to stackexchange. If my answer helped you please set it as being correct, otherwise leave a comment on it and let us know if it didn't. That way we can help you find the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Look in this directory: /app/design/frontend/YOURSITE/default/layout/

See if there are the following files in there: "paypal.xml" and "checkout.xml"... delete those if they are there. (Make a backup copy of them first of course.)

Answer (score 1):

found this solution and it worked for me :-)

> After look in everywhere I found out it was just an update on the
>   layout. I went to
>   /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
>   and changed that around the line 36:

adding the id “checkout-payment-method-load” to fieldset so change line 36 from 
`fieldset`
to 
`fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load"`

source:
http://blog.mdnsolutions.com/index.php/magento-1-8-payment-not-loading-on-checkout/